# Start CSS Animations JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

How can I start CSS animations with js?
the first line (webkitAnimation) works but the other ones don't.

```
anim_logo.style.webkitAnimation="threesixty 3s";
anim_logo.style.mozAnimation="threesixty 3s";
anim_logo.style.oAnimation="threesixty 3s";
anim_logo.style.animation="threesixty 3s";
```

why?

[live preview](http://s0ulp1xel.x10.mx/?p=home) (Click on the Ninja Star)

Comment: I can't deduce a specific question here, but for animation, jQuery's various effect calls are good places to start...

Comment: Could you please check if you put the second or the last one first if it works in firefox?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You better make a separate class with that animation and simply attach it to your element when needed:

```
anim_logo.setAttribute("class", yourAnimationClass);
```

**UPDATE**

To remove the newly added class you can use a delayed function:

```
function animateMe() {
    anim_logo.setAttribute( "class", yourAnimationClass );
    setTimeout( function() {
        anim_logo.setAttribute( "class", "" );
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: the question is why his code only works in WebKit, not what he should replace it with.

Comment: @Zoltan Toth   I would use this ^^ if I could remove the attribute when it is done animating.

Comment: @s0ulp1xel updated with the idea how you can remove the class after the animation

Comment: @11684 When you hang around a little bit more on SO you'll know that sometimes the straight answer to the OP's question is not the best one and you're free (and actually encouraged) to suggest a cleaner/better solution.

Comment: You can use the property `className` instead of `setAttribute("class", ...)`, by the way  Also, any browser supporting CSS animations supports `classList`, I believe, so: `anim_logo.classList.add(yourAnimationClass);`